# Cronjob won't execute on 1and1 server

Tags: cron

I have 1and1 web hosting. I am supposed to be able to set up cron jobs using crontab to execute on the server. I have a job set up as follows (including showing the full path to my PHP installation):

```
(uiserver):u*******:~ > which php5.4
/usr/local/bin/php5.4

(uiserver):u*******:~ > crontab -l
20 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php5.4 /kunden/homepages/40/d*******/htdocs/job.php
```

If I execute the command manually in the terminal, it runs fine. But the cron job never runs.

Am I missing something obvious?

I've tried checking the cron logs, but I just get permission denied, unfortunately, so that was no help for troubleshooting. The joys of being on somebody else's server, I guess...

Comment: I know this is late but, I just had a similar issue with mine. I was using a mysqli statement in my php file and I saw that you were pointing to /php5.4. I did that on mine and solved my issue. Your call to the job looks fine. Here's what mine looks like.

20 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php5.4 /kunden/homepages/5/d********/htdocs/cronjobs/job.php

Comment: So, it ended up being that I my crontab file had passed through a Windows environment and therefore had `CRLF` as the end-of-line. Crontab wouldn't complain when I saved it, but it wouldn't be able to execute. Incidentally, something that could have been diagnosed in 10 seconds if 1and1 had let me check my logs. I'll be switching to EC2 as soon as my 1and1 contract is up...

Comment: Ahhhh damn. Well glad you got it figured out. I also use 1and1 and was trying to figure out how to gain access to my logs which led me here lol

Comment: I had a problem with access rights, i had to set rights for the script to execute to 700

Comment: FYI only php is allowed in user crontab on ionos shared hosting package.